# Google 2-way & XRDP?

Tags: 16.04, server, xrdp, two-factor-authentication

I installed the 2-Way login like in this manual:

[how to setup two factor authentication in Ubuntu for Ubuntu users using Google authenticator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609117/how-to-setup-two-factor-authentication-in-ubuntu-for-ubuntu-users-using-google-a/869023#869023)

So now I'm trying to get it working with XRDP.
I tried a few things, but in general I'm out of ideas now..
Does anybody have it running already?

Thank's in advance for any help!

Comment: "I tried a few things" - what exactly did you try? what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` and replace line:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

with

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so forward_pass
auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass
```

Now when ever you login or use sudo, password is asked which is now in form password + authentication code from authenticator. Example: `password123123`.