# Avoid verification code request when using sudo using Google authenticator

Tags: authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication

I've just activated the [two factor authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609117/how-to-setup-two-factor-authentication-in-ubuntu-for-ubuntu-users-using-google-a) using Google authenticator and I'm now required to provide the verification code any time that I use `sudo`. How to avoid the authentication step when using `sudo` while preserving the layer of securing when logging in?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question while looking for a solution to this problem myself. This is how I have managed to have Google Authentication in the existing services except when using sudo. I assume you have added the following line to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` in order to enable the Google Authentication:

```
auth    required    pam_google_authenticator.so    nullok
```

In the same `/etc/pam.d` directory you should have a file called `sudo` which handles sudo authentication. This file should contain a line

```
@include common-auth
```

This is pulling the content of the common-auth file which is forcing the additional google authentication to be implemented.

NOTE -> you should make a backup of your sudo file before proceeding (just in case).

In order to solve this, copy the contents of the `common-auth` file into the sudo file below the `@include common-auth` line.
Then comment/remove the lines

```
@include common-auth
```

and

```
auth    required    pam_google_authenticator.so    nullok
```